# Using delay and loop on guitar means Pink Floyd and Gilmour in particular

Tags: guitar

I have a strange thing going around me. I am a keyboard player, but I also play guitar. And when on guitar, I love delay and loop, especially in combination. Somehow people always perceive this as a Pink Floyd kind of thing used by Gilmour only. Is it true that delay and loop on guitar is a signature of only Gilmour's style?